# Python - Dijsktra's Algorithm Distance Problem

Tags: python, dijkstra

I've run into a problem with my code, i'm not able to calculate the distance to a node from the starting node. I have a text file of the form:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

This represents the node distances in the graph. Here is my code, unfortunately, despite trying a few different methods I still keep coming up with various error messages.

```
infinity = 1000000 
invalid_node = -1 
startNode = 0

class Node:
      distFromSource = infinity
      previous = invalid_node
      visited = False

def populateNodeTable(): 
    nodeTable = []
    index =0
    f = open('route.txt', 'r')
    for line in f: 
      node = map(int, line.split(',')) 
      nodeTable.append(Node()) 
      print nodeTable[index].previous 
      print nodeTable[index].distFromSource 
      index +=1

    nodeTable[startNode].distFromSource = 0 

    return nodeTable

def tentativeDistance(currentNode, nodeTable):
    nearestNeighbour = []
    for currentNode in nodeTable:
#     if Node[currentNode].distFromSource + currentDistance = startNode + currentNode
#      currentDistance = currentNode.distFromSource + nodeTable.currentNode
         currentNode.previous = currentNode
         currentNode.length = currentDistance
         currentNode.visited = True
         currentNode +=1
         nearestNeighbour.append(currentNode)
         print nearestNeighbour

    return nearestNeighbour

def shortestPath (nearestNeighbour)
    shortestPath = []
    f = open ('spf.txt', 'r')
    f.close()

currentNode = startNode

if __name__ == "__main__":
    populateNodeTable()
    tentativeDistance(currentNode,populateNodeTable())
```

The lines starting with '#' in my tentativeDistance function is the section giving me trouble. I've looked at some other implementations on the web though they confuse me

Comment: The formatting on the code doesn't seem right.  It makes it tough to follow.  Could you try to fix the indentation?

Comment: The indentation is broken. You may want to check that you were not mixing tabs and spaces before you pasted it here

Comment: It's been edited, works for me, well, apart from the function that's giving me the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been programming the Dijkstra's Algorithm in Python a few months ago; its tested and it should work:

```
def dijkstra(u,graph):
  n = graph.numNodes
    l = { u : 0 } ; W = graph.V()
    F = [] ; k = {}
    for i in range(0,n):
      lv,v = min([ (l[lk],lk) for lk in l.keys() if lk in W ])
      W.remove(v)
      if v!=u: F.append(k[v])
      for v1 in [ v2 for v2 in graph.G(v) if v2 in W ]:
        if v1 not in l or l[v]+graph.w(v,v1) < l[v1]:
          l[v1] = l[v] + graph.w(v,v1)
          k[v1] = (v,v1)
    return l,F
```

You need a class Graph with Method V() (which yields the graphs nodes), w(v1,v2) (which yields the weight of the edge (v1,v2)), remove (which removes an edge from a graph) and attribute numNodes (which yields the number of nodes in the graph) and G(v) which yields the neighborhood of node v.

Comment: Thanks for replying, the node details are being read from a text file, which seems to work ok, i'm just stuck on how I can get my program to find the distances to each node from the source node correctly